# Deserialized object instance without class definition

Tags: java, serialization

In anyone aware of a tool/script/program/whatever to create a java object instance from a binary java serialized object?

I don't have the .class file, so I can't ( afaik ) simply create an ObjectInputStream and load it from there.

This object has the default serialization mechanism, and I'm trying to debug a problem we have.

Anyone?

Comment: How do you end up with a serialized object that doesn't have a .class file?

Comment: eeerhmmm... It's a long history. Once upon a time a software developer ... ohh .. .nevermind.

Comment: Ok, I found the .class files, they are inside .jar "files" ( as expected )  which happen to be inside a DB :) I'm about the change the question. Get files from blob :)

Comment: .jar files stored inside the DB? I thought I'd heard it all.

Comment: Oracle supports RUNNING jarfiles stored inside the DB... Oh the joy :)

Comment: @brd6644: Really? What about ldap class loader? :) That is jar files inside a ldap server ;)

Answer (score 1):

There was a rather detailed post about the format in JavaWorld recently... Might be worth reading.

Link: http://www.javaworld.com/community/node/2915

Comment: Yeap, something along this lines. I know there are a couple of tools like asm or other bytecode manipulation tools, but I have never use them before, so I don't know what's the best tool

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to accomplish is very similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941983/how-to-send-a-class-over-the-wire/941997#941997)

Comment: Uh?... What is the answer? Using object serialization/deserialization? I don't have .class file

Comment: The answer was to get the .class file from a URL.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class with the correct name and `serialVersionUID`. Implement `readObject`. Use `ObjectInputStream.readFields` to get the `ObjectInputStrem.GetFields`.

Comment: I've got InvalidClassException. I guess I need to know what's the correct serialVersionUID. Exception in thread "main" java.io.InvalidClassException: com.o.a.I; enum descriptor has non-zero serialVersionUID: 12885773312

Comment: How to know the correct serialVersionUID without the class?